# Installing Oracle on Debian to access an external Database

Tags: oracle, debian, sqlplus

I am a little lost with the current documentation I have.

I am trying to access an oracle server within a Network, using a Debian Box. Ideally, what I'd need to do is to cron job something into SQL plus, so it performs periodically.

My scripts are ready, but I am not sure how to do the instalation part, or what to install in order to get access to SQLPlus. Does I need the full-fledged oracle client? Oracle XE? Will SquirrelSQL work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the Oracle client, not the full database install. You can [download it here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-linuxsoft-085393.html). From the sound of it, you don't need the full client.

Comment: I managed to do it with the oracle XE and configuring the parameters accordingly. Thanks!